Ensuring non-nullable navigation in EF Core
I have an entity DataSuggestion which owns Data. Data itself owns Material & Coordinates.
public class DataSuggestion : Entity<Guid>
{
    public Guid DataId { get; init; }
    public Email Email { get; init; }
    public Comment Comment { get; init; }
    public Data Data { get; init; }

    public DataSuggestion(Email email, 
        Comment comment, 
        IEnumerable<Coordinate> coordinates, 
        Material material) : this()
    {
        Email = email;
        Comment = comment;

        Data = new Data(coordinates, material);
    }

    private DataSuggestion()
    { }
}

public class Data : ValueObject<Data>
{
    private readonly List<Coordinate> _coordinates;
    public IEnumerable<Coordinate> Coordinates => _coordinates.AsReadOnly();
    public Material Material { get; init; }

    public Data(IEnumerable<Coordinate> coordinates, 
        Material material) : this()
    {
        _coordinates = coordinates.ToList();
        Material = material;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EF Core constructor
    /// </summary>
    private Data()
    { }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAttributesToIncludeInEqualityCheck()
    {
        return [_coordinates, Material];
    }
}

The configuration is as follows
builder.OwnsOne(ds => ds.Comment);
builder.OwnsOne(ds => ds.Email);
        
builder.OwnsOne(ds => ds.Data, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
        {
            ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(d => d.Material);
            ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(d => d.Coordinates);
            ownedNavigationBuilder.Navigation(d => d.Material).IsRequired();
        });

I get an exception:

Entity type 'Data' is an optional dependent using table sharing and containing other dependents without any required non shared property to identify whether the entity exists. If all nullable properties contain a null value in database then an object instance won't be created in the query causing nested dependent's values to be lost. Add a required property to create instances with null values for other properties or mark the incoming navigation as required to always create an instance.

As far as I understand the exception states that if none of Data's properties must not be null. However, I've already marked Material as required (EDIT: by this I mean ownedNavigationBuilder.Navigation(d => d.Material).IsRequired();), and it's not possible to do the same for collections.
Also I'm a bit confused: DataSuggestion owns Comment which contains only string property, but such an exception is not thrown.
I've tried to mark whole Data as required but to no avail.
The questions are:

Why should we mark all properties as required and not just some of them?
How to deal with the exception if I can't mark Coordinates as required?

Thank you!
EDIT: I've found out that the order of instructions matter and if I put
uilder.Navigation(ds => ds.Data).IsRequired();

After
builder.OwnsOne(ds => ds.Data, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
    {
        ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(d => d.Material);
        ownedNavigationBuilder.Navigation(d => d.Material).IsRequired();
        ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(d => d.Coordinates);
    });

Then it works, but still why isn't this enough?
ownedNavigationBuilder.Navigation(d => d.Material).IsRequired();


Please post the definition of class DataSuggestion and class Data.

When you say "marked as required" - do you mean you used the required modifier - or the [Required] attribute - or something else? If you meant the required modifier, then you can't do that: it doesn't work with EF, because EF is always able to load one entity without any other related entities (i.e. await dbContext.DataSuggestion.ToListAsync() without doing await dbContext.DataSuggestion.Include( ds => ds.Material ).Include( ds => ds.Coordinates ).ToListAsync() - that's why you cannot make EF navigation properties required - and why they also should be marked as #nullable.

Note that you need to ensure it's done such that it doesn't change the nature of a "required" or "non-nullable" FK constraint - you can still have those - but the .NET entity class reference properties need to be nullable because navigation properties can always be null if you don't load related entities (and if you have lazy-loading disabled, which you should have...)

@Dai I've updated the post, should have posted the classes initially

@Dai sorry for the confusion, I mean [Required] (or .IsRequired() as I've declared it)

Material and Coordinates aren't properties but Owned Types/Collections, and if Data itself does not contain any non-null properties, then no instance of Data will be created, regardless of Material values.
I've annotated the exception message to help explain it.

Entity type 'Data' is an optional dependent (you didn't use .IsRequired() on Data itself) using table sharing and
containing other dependents (Material and Coordinates) without any required non shared property (Data does not contain a property, owned types/collections don't count)
to identify whether the entity exists. If all nullable properties (This is the case if you don't have any properties)
contain a null value in database then an object instance (of Data) won't be
created in the query causing nested dependent's (Material) values to be lost. Add
a required property to create instances with null values for other
properties or mark the incoming navigation as required to always
create an instance.


Thank you for the answer, it really helped me understand the issue. However, I still have something that confuses me:
I also have a class 'Comment' beeing owned by DataSuggestion
'public class Comment : ValueObject
{
public string Text { get; init; }
public Comment(string text)
{
Text = text;
}
protected override IEnumerable GetAttributesToIncludeInEqualityCheck() => [Text];
}'
I fail to understand why the same exception isn't thrown?Is this 'cause of the constructor that accepts a string, while 'Data' has an empty constructor for EF?

Comment has a property Text that is non-nullable and can be used to determine if the whole comment should be instantiated or not.
